# How does one calculate the evolution of a species in a low energy plasma over time?

Tags: mathematical-physics, computational-physics, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory

I am currently working on a global modeling program for low temperature plasma and I have hit a wall. My goal is to graph the evolution of a species as a function of time using an approximation of the electron energy distribution function (EEDF) along with other information (composition in terms of mole fraction, temperature, pressure, etc.) So far, I have obtained an approximation for the EEDF from which I have calculated the rate constants for certain reactions. I noticed how kinetics in both plasma and general chemistry are similar in many ways, however, I still don't know how to use these rate constants to determine how the species density changes with time. How does one derive the function for the change of species density over time in a low temperature plasma?

Comment: Have you started with the Vlasov equation?  Once that works, then you can add Coulomb collisions to get a version of the Boltzmann equation.

Comment: I have looked into the Vlasov equation, but from what I have read, it only applies to a system in which we ignore collisions. The model I am developing needs to be able to find the concentration of the products of the collision. Furthermore, I have already made use of the Boltzmann Equation to derive the EEDF.

Comment: If you have a self-consistent model already, then are you just concerned with the velocity moments of each constituent species?  If so, then you should be able to calculate the velocity moments separately for each species since you can distinguish particles in your model.  The zeroth moment is the number density.